# How to pull image on top for small only with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column that has a little blurb of text and then on the right hand side (in anything of size), a small image.

On mobile screens, I would like to pull the small image on top. I have tried different variations of the bootstrap classes below and I cannot seem to pull/push so that mobile appears on top with the blurbs of text below on mobile

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-9 text-right main-block">
                <div class = "col-xs-11 pull-right h1 quote">
                    Hey, look at this text!! 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-right attribute h2">-SOME MORE TEXT</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-right attribute">TXT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-3">
                <img class ="top-right-round parallel-corner" src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think mobile first!  Move your image above the text.  Then on larger screens, pull/push column alignment.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">Hey, look at this text!!</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">SOME MORE TEXT</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">TXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```